# can't populate volume using configMap

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I am trying run a spring boot application whose application.properties file will be used as a kubernetes configMap.

While deploying the app, I am adding a volume for this config file. But somehow, it is not creating properties file at mount path.

configMap name : integration-properties
Data :

```
application.properties:
http.stub.api.host=localhost
http.stub.api.port=8080
http.stub.api.path=stub-api
```

Deployment.yaml file :

```
volumeMounts:
              - name: config-volume
                mountPath: /opt/build/
volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: integration-properties
            items:
               - key: application.properties
                 path: application.properties
```

When I run this application, it says, "/opt/build/application.properties" does not exists.

Please let me know for any further configuration required, if any and steps to do them.

Answer (score 0):

So define configMap as:

```
data:
  application.properties: |
    http.stub.api.host=localhost
    http.stub.api.port=8080
    http.stub.api.path=stub-api
```

or you can also create directly from the `application.properties` file

```
kubectl create configmap integration-properties --from-file=application.properties=<path to file>
```

Your `deployment.yaml` file looks good to me there isn't any problem.